# How to get part of a string from the end

Tags: c#, substring

Given this string:

`01/01/2000 Club Lets Rock  Jonny`

As you can see, I have 3 informations divided by spaces, and the second one `Club Lets Rock` its one information with 2 blank spaces. Jony is the name of a person who send me this  informations, I need to know, how may I get JUST the name of the person ? Is there a way to get it from the end of the string 'till it reaches the first blank space ?

I know there's a lot of others threads about `substring` but none of them are like this. I also read the articles from some sites that explain `substring` but couldn't find an appropriate for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the string by using the space char as separator and get the Last item.

Something like:

```
string name = "01/01/2000 Club Lets Rock Jonny".Split(' ').Last();
```

Comment: I'm felling so idiot now u.u . I saw the ´.Last()` but couldn't use correct, Now it's working hehe... Thank you @dutzu

Comment: @Ghaleon you can do it without Linq also by doing something like this:  string source = "01/01/2000 Club Lets Rock Jonny";
    string name = source.Split(' ')[source.Length -1];

Comment: This is quick and easy but, could be considered as overkill, why split the whole string just to find the end. If you need to enumerate the other parts of the string, then this makes obvious sense.

Comment: Hey @dutzu, these method without Linq gave me an error: `index out of matriz limite` But if there is no problem using Linq, I'll go with it.

Comment: @Ghaleon True, the Linq version is safer, just remember to check the resulting string with String.IsNullOrEmpty to protect yourself.

Comment: @dutzu Sorry I'm a `noob` on C#, how could I do that ?

Comment: @Ghaleon Just,after this line of code that returns the last element be caraful because the Linq extension method will not crash like the index version will if the input string is not valid, but will return a null. if you try the code i wrote with an input string that is empty then you might have problems in your code. But that should not happen anyway, so if you are a beginner don't worry about that just yet.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
var yourString = "01/01/2000 Club Lets Rock Jonny";
var everythingAfterTheLastSpace = 
    yourString.SubString(yourString.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: You'd need to `+1` the index otherwise the name would have a space at the beginning.